# Change TIFF palette from 8 bit into 32 bit

Tags: c#, image, tiff

I have some set of TIFF files (8-bit palette). I need to change the bit depth into 32 bit.
I tried the code below, but getting an error, that the parameter is not correct... Could you help me to fix it? Or maybe some1 is able to suggest some different solution for my problem.

```
public static class TiffConverter
{
    public static void Convert8To32Bit(string fileName)
    {
        BitmapSource bitmapSource;
        using (Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];
        }

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            ImageCodecInfo tiffCodec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID.Equals(ImageFormat.Tiff.Guid));
            if (tiffCodec != null)
            {
                Image image = BitmapFromSource(bitmapSource);
                EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters();
                parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 32);
                image.Save(stream, tiffCodec, parameters);
            }
        }
    }

    private static Bitmap BitmapFromSource(BitmapSource bitmapSource)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
            enc.Save(outStream);
            bitmap = new Bitmap(outStream);
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**[edit]**

I noticed that the error appears in this line:

```
image.Save(stream, tiffCodec, parameters);
```

`ArgumentException occured: Parameter is not valid.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error you're getting is on the line:

```
parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 32);
```

then the problem is that the compiler cannot know if you're referring `System.Text.Encoder` or `System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder`...

Your code should look like this to to avoid any ambiguity:

```
parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.ColorDepth, 32);
```

---

**Edit:**

This is an alternative (and tested :)) way of doing the same thing:

```
Image inputImg = Image.FromFile("input.tif");

var outputImg = new Bitmap(inputImg.Width, inputImg.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(outputImg))
    gr.DrawImage(inputImg, new Rectangle(0, 0, inputImg.Width, inputImg.Height));

outputImg.Save("output.tif", ImageFormat.Tiff);
```

Comment: Nope, cuz I created the using like this:
`using Encoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder;`

Comment: Damn, it's my bad, sry. There is a problem with parameter in line: `image.Save(stream, tiffCodec, parameters);`, but still don't know why...

Comment: Seems like `32` is not an acceptable value here. Did you try with a value of `24L` (corresponding to 8 bpp)?